# How I get comma-separated values form table in symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, find-in-set

I have a MySQL table which contains comma-separated values like this:

first row=(A,AB)
second row=(AC, AE)

I want to select the rows which have A in their set not AC OR AE. I am using symfony2 in my code.

```
$query = $query->andWhere("FIND_IN_SET('".trim($tag)."',advNews.advNewsTags)");
```

Its Return Error: Expected known function, got 'FIND_IN_SET'

But if i use query in sqlyog like

```
select * from advice_news where  adv_news_type = 'news' AND FIND_IN_SET  ('sdf',adv_news_tags)
```

its work fine.

Tell me any solution i will use FIND_IN_SET in symfony2.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have no possibility to update the current database schema ?

Comment: You may use the `expr()->like()` function but it will work only if the string of the tag won't be a substring of another tag. For example, if you search `%animal%` it will also match with `%animals%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [FunctionNode](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) to Doctrine and Symfony. I had the same problem with `SOUNDS LIKE`. You can find my solution at http://piotrpasich.com/full-text-searching/ in SOUNDEX chapter.